# Client_fetch_error session (next-auth v3)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

i have big problem with next-auth credential-provider when i build my next.js project i get error [next-auth][error][client_fetch_error]

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error session FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

**** i want to deploy my project local

that is my code

//env.local

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000
SECRET=SYoUMVkWrAVwv+qDJ+E43kmS7uMIJY3R7AS53tLNclk=
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/healthycrm
```

//[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
import User from "../../../models/mongoModels/user";
import connectDB from "../../../middleware/mondodb";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const user = await User.findOne({
          EmpUserName: credentials.userName,
        }).exec();
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("No user Found");
        }
        const cheakPassWord = user.EmpPassword === credentials.password;
        if (!cheakPassWord) {
          throw new Error("password is wrong");
        }
        return { name: user.EmpName, email: user.id, image: user.imgPath };
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    encryption: true,
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
    session: async (session, user) => {
      const data = await User.findById(user.email).exec();
      const premissions = data.Premissions
        ? data.Premissions.map((x) => x.id)
        : [];
      const Emps = data.Premissions ? data.Emps.map((x) => x.id) : [];
      session.user.jobID = data.EmpJobID;
      session.user.MID = data._id;
      session.user.List = data.EmpLists;
      session.user.AreasQ = data.EmpAreasQ;
      session.user.AreasG = data.EmpAreasG;
      session.user.EmpJobName = data.EmpJobName;
      session.user.EmpDepartID = data.EmpDepartID;
      session.user.EmpDepartName = data.EmpDepartName;
      session.user.EmpQtayID = data.EmpQtayID;
      session.user.EmpGomla = data.EmpGomla;
      session.user.directMangerId = data.directMangerId;
      session.user.directMangerName = data.directMangerName;
      session.user.EmpClassesQ = data.EmpClassesQ;
      session.user.EmpClassesG = data.EmpClassesG;
      session.user.Premissions = premissions;
      session.user.Emps = Emps;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
  },
});

export default connectDB(handler);
```

Comment: You have to modify the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable to the actual URL of the app when you deploy it to a hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution: Run `npm run dev` during build